# Nesting Angular Material custom components themes

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I created two custom Angular Material themes (blue, red).

I have an `IconComponent` (selector: `my-app-icon`) that I want to design using themes, according to the ["Theming your components"](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components) Material documentation.

Now, in my `styles.scss`, I have:

```
@mixin icon-theme($theme) {
  $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
  $accent: map-get($theme, accent);

  my-app-icon {
    background-color: mat-color($primary);
    color: mat-color($accent, A400);
  }
}

.blue-theme {
   @include angular-material-theme($blue-theme);
   @include icon-theme($blue-theme);
}

.red-theme {
   @include angular-material-theme($red-theme);
   @include icon-theme($red-theme);
}
```

It works well, but if I want to nest my themes, such as:

```
<div class="blue-theme">
  <my-app-icon></my-app-icon>
  <div class="red-theme">
    <my-app-icon></my-app-icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Only the first theme declaration** (`blue-theme` here) **is effective** (for the two icons). That makes sense, because my mixin imply a double declaration of `my-app-icon {}`.

How can I get the expected behaviour (first icon blue, second red) ?

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple themes *at the same time* within an application requires a different approach than implementing *switchable* themes globally which is what you have implemented.

You need to implement a "theme" or color feature in your component - something like the way Angular Material does for "color" options (primary, accent, warn) on some components via the `CanColor` base class.

In a nutshell, your component has some mechanism to specify its theme, and you implement the styling within the component.

That could be as simple as a class:

Usage:

```
<my-app-icon class="red-theme"></my-app-icon>
```

SCSS:

```
:host(.red-theme) {
  @include icon-theme($red-theme); 
}
:host(.blue-theme) {
  @include icon-theme($blue-theme); 
}
```

Or it could be more sophisticated like an `Input` for the theme property:

Usage:

```
<my-app-icon theme="red"></my-app-icon>
```

TS:

```
@Input() theme: string = 'red'; // defaults to red
@HostBinding('class.red-theme') get isRedTheme() { return this.theme === 'red'; };
@HostBinding('class.blue-theme') get isBlueTheme() { return this.theme === 'blue'; };
```

The same SCSS as above would apply here.

You could optionally style only the necessary parts of the component:

IconComponent Template:

```
<mat-icon [ngClass]="{'blue-theme': theme === 'blue', 'red-theme': theme !== 'blue'}">{{iconName}}</mat-icon>
```

SCSS:

```
:host {
  mat-icon
    &.red-theme {
      color: red;
    }
    &.blue-theme {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

But this might be more tricky to do via the theming mixin.

Have a look at the `CanColor` class for ideas:

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/8.1.x/src/material/core/common-behaviors/color.ts